# Any C# .NET Libraries to export images into a PPT File

Tags: c#, .net, image, powerpoint, gif

I would like to export a series of images [JPEG/Gif files] into a power point presentation. Are there any .NET libraries that I can use for this purpose ? Looking for a library, which can help me create ppt from C# .NET, and import the images into slides and arrange them in  slides [ for instance i could chose to have 6 images per slide / 2 images per slide ].

Appreciate any help in this regard..

Regards
Vidya Sagar.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at [Aspose.Slides.](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx)

Their library allows generating PPT files via code. They have a very intuitive and simple API, and are very active in their development and improvements of their libraries.